# futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join) runs all tasks parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I have multiple completable futures created as:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> xxx);
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> xxx);
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = Lists.newArrayList(future1, future2);
```

When I run below, are these two future tasks running in parallel? Will exception throw by one future blocks the other?

```
futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```

Comment: They are even running in parallel when you don’t execute the `forEach` loop. The `join` call only *waits* for a result, it doesn’t affect the ongoing operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling [`CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)) the tasks are submitted to the [common `ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()). This pool is managed by the JVM.

Since it is a common pool, no guarantees are made/can be made as to whether the tasks **actually** run concurrent or in parallel (other tasks may be submitted to the pool, or the pool may have only one thread at its disposal, resulting in a sequential exeuction of the tasks). But in a best-case scenario, they will be processed in parallel.

An `Exception` in one task will not have any effects on another task (unless explictly implemented in the tasks). In fact, without further configuration, the `Exception` will be silently ignored (to catch `Exception`s, an [explicit `UncaughtExceptionHandler` can be set when constructing a `ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory,java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler,boolean,int,int,int,java.util.function.Predicate,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))). One can also figure out if a `ComletableFuture` has completed with an `Exception` by calling [`isDone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isDone()) (to know if the task has been executed) and [`isCompletedExceptionally()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isCompletedExceptionally()) (to know whether the task has completed with an `Exception`). The `Exception` itself can be obtained by calling [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isDone()), but one should beware that the `Exception` is **thrown, not returned** when calling `get()`.

Comment: When the exception is remembered and thrown by `get` (the same applies to `join`), there is no sense in saying at the same time that exceptions were “silently ignored”. Since exceptions thrown by the supplier are caught and stored, they will never be passed to a handler for *uncaught* exceptions.